# Appengine ndb dynamic choices

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

How is it possible to implement dynamic choices in Google APpengine ndb?

```
class Choice(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class List(ndb.Model):
    choices = ndb.KeyProperty(Choice, choices=Choice.query(keys_only=True).fetch(), repeated=True)
```

This code exit with `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys_only'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code that is causing the error you mentioned:

`(keys-only=True)`

should be

`(keys_only=True)`

Also, that argument needs to be passed to `.fetch()`, not to `.query()`:

`choices=Choice.query().fetch(keys_only=True)`

But regardless of that, getting the list of choices that way is not possible, defining it at the ndb model definition level cannot be dynamic.

You can implement it at the application level, obtaining the list of available choices and checking the values being added to the `choices` property against that list before `.put()`. It may be a bit tricky if you need to do that transactionally since you can't make the (non-ancestor) query inside transactions. To address a similar problem I used memcache to store the list of choices obtained by query (outside a transaction) and get it from there inside transactions.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. now the error is `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys_only'`...

Comment: @user2154587 you should pass the `keys_only` parameter to the `fetch()` function instead of the `query()` one.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do? That last line doesn't seem to make much sense.